# Windows 7: npm uglifyjs "is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: node.js, npm, uglifyjs

I installed npm 2.15.9, works fine anywhere when I open the Command Prompt.

I (allegedly) installed uglifyjs by typing

```
npm install -g uglifyjs
```

I tried with and without -g, and I ran it in the folder where I want to use it. Even after doing so and not receiving any error, typing "uglifyjs" or "node uglifyjs" in the CMD terminal return the standard error message - uglifyjs is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: yes, I tried closing and reopening the CMD window at each step.

Comment: Did you close and reopen the cmd window? Sometimes something like that is needed.

Comment: Yep, I tried that too.

Comment: What is the output of `npm install -g uglifyjs`?

Comment: C:\Users\emanuelec\AppData\Roaming\npm\uglifyjs -> C:\Users\emanuelec\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\uglifyjs\bin\uglifyjs
uglifyjs@2.4.10 C:\Users\emanuelec\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\uglifyjs
├── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
├── async@0.2.10
├── yargs@1.3.3
└── source-map@0.1.34 (amdefine@1.0.0)

Answer (score 7):

uglifyjs is deprecated - use uglify-js instead.

```
npm install -g uglify-js
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Does npm think it's installed? (`npm ls -g | findstr uglify` should reveal it).
2. Try `npm config get prefix` and, with that path:

   - Is that that folder on your `%PATH%` (`echo %PATH%`)?
   - Is `npm` is actually installing the binaries *in that* folder (`dir C:\Users\emanuelec\AppData\Roaming\npm`).

It does seem to that 'bin links' are being generated (from your comment above, `C:\Users\emanuelec\AppData\Roaming\npm\uglifyjs`), so I suspect the `npm\` folder is not in your path, or is being clobbered by something.

Comment: The first command returns... a strange output:

Ôöé ÔööÔöÇÔö¼ uglify-js@2.7.3
Ôöé   Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
Ôöé Ôö£ÔöÇÔö¼ uglify-js@2.7.0
Ôöé Ôöé Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
Ôöé Ôöé Ôöé Ôöé ÔööÔöÇÔö¼ uglify-js@2.2.5
Ôö£ÔöÇÔö¼ uglify-js@2.7.3
Ôöé Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
ÔööÔöÇÔö¼ uglifyjs@2.4.10
  Ôö£ÔöÇÔöÇ uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2

Comment: The second command returns

C:\Users\emanuelec\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: Finally, I checked the folder C:\Users\emanuelec\AppData\Roaming\npm and indeed contains references to uglifyjs. I have no way to verify if those are the correct files.